# android : How to filter items in firebase by referring another database reference property

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get only items that are in users favorites that has required city.
For example, if the user has 20 favorite items and if user wants to filter favorites that exists in specific city how to filter it?

Sorry for my English. If anything is not clear, ask me.

[image]

Comment: thanks itsmyterybox for improving my post

Comment: there can be 2 approaches : get user's fav data and use the below method to filter cities

or filter get the city key from the city node and apply the filter on user favourities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.you.package.name;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by harkal on 26-10-2018.
 */

public class Filter {

    private static final String TAG = "";

    private String city;
    private String user;

    private OnFoodDataCallBack onFoodDataCallBack;

    public void setOnFoodDataCallBack(OnFoodDataCallBack onFoodDataCallBack) {
        this.onFoodDataCallBack = onFoodDataCallBack;
    }

    public Filter(String city, String user) {
        this.city = city;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void init(){
        DatabaseReference userFavRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Path/To/Users/");
        userFavRef.child(user).child("favourites").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //now get the favs with the filtered city
                    int initKey = 0;
                    final int totalFavs = (int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    final ArrayList<String> foodsWithCity = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        initKey = initKey+1;

                        String foodKey = snapshot.getKey();//this is the key for every fav food 

                        //now query all the food nodes with the city

                        DatabaseReference foodRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Path/To/Foods/");
                        Query query = foodRef.child(foodKey).orderByChild("city").equalTo(city);
                        final int finalInitKey = initKey;
                        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    //there is a food item with the queried city

                                    foodsWithCity.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                                    if(finalInitKey == totalFavs){
                                        if(onFoodDataCallBack != null){
                                            onFoodDataCallBack.onSuccess(foodsWithCity);
                                        }
                                    }                                    
                                }else{
                                    //there is no food with this city
                                    if(finalInitKey == totalFavs){
                                        if(onFoodDataCallBack != null){
                                            onFoodDataCallBack.onFailed("there is no food with this city");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                if(onFoodDataCallBack != null){
                                    onFoodDataCallBack.onFailed(databaseError.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }else{
                    if(onFoodDataCallBack != null){
                        onFoodDataCallBack.onFailed("no fav data about user");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                if(onFoodDataCallBack != null){
                    onFoodDataCallBack.onFailed(databaseError.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnFoodDataCallBack{

        void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> foodWithCities);
        void onFailed(String error);

    }

}
```

you can use the code this way :

```
Filter filter = new Filter("washingaton", "user_01");
        filter.setOnFoodDataCallBack(new Filter.OnFoodDataCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> foodWithCities) {
                //here is the data you wanted
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(String error) {
                //handle the error and change ui accordingly
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailed: "+error);
            }
        });
        filter.init();
```

hope it helps

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the db-structure below :

```
root : {
     user_01 : {
           fav_01 : {
                 data : val,
                 city : "city_01"
           }
           fav_02 : {
                 data : val,
                 city : "city_02"
           }
           fav_03 : {
                 data : val,
                 city : "city_01"
           }
     }
}
```

now make such query in andorid :

```
String user = "user_01";
String city_name = "city_01";
int limit = 10;
DatabaseReference favRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("root/").child(user);
    Query query = favRef.orderByChild("city").equalTo(city_name).limitToFirst(limit);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.toString());
              //you will get fav_01 and fav_3 objects
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: "+databaseError.toString());
         }
});
```

hope it helps you
happy coding :)

Comment: well i didn't see that image

Comment: Har Kal .... your database suggestion will make duplication. is there another way to make it by referring other database reference or filter them in bindViewHolder of the adapter

Comment: @Mehiretab actually i didnt see that image before and simply gave an example
i have commented on your question
have a look at that

Comment: in order to complete the answer, how to bind this type of data in to recyclerview using firebase recycler adapter?

Comment: @Mehiretab which answer you are using ? this one or the other one ? 


the other one is better i think

Comment: Yeah I am using it. could you give the answer with binding in firebase recycler adapter?